# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file for php code

Tags: php, database

Whenever I try to view the site I get an error message. Here is the code:

```
<?php
 $server = '127.0.0.1';
 $username = 'root';
 $db_name = 'auth';

try{
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username);}
  catch(PDOException $e){
  die( "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
   }

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

  // enter the new user in the database
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, passowrd) VALUES (;email, :password);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->bindParam':email'],_POST['email'];
  $stmt->bindParam((':password',password_hash(POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

  if( $stmt->execute() ):
   die('Success');

  endif;
 endif;

   ?>
```

I cannot figure out why it is saying that the end bracket for the php code is unexpected.

Comment: Syntax errors everywhere. `;` instead of `:` on `;email`. Missing `$_`s, missing end quotes to end strings. Missing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

There are many syntax errors in your script.

- In query string `;email` should be `:email`. Also the close *double quote* is missing

  `$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, passowrd) VALUES (:email, :password)";`

  ```
                                                    ^^^^               ^^^
  ```
- Parenthesis is missing for `bindParam`. Also `$_` is missing before `POST`

  `$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);`

  ```
                 ^^^                      ^^^^
  ```
- Mismatch `(` and `$_POST` issues below the statement:

  `$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));`

Hope it will be clear to you.